# Parameter being set to undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement, parameters

I am working on a school project which is based on the game Wheel of Fortune. Currently, I am working on having the computer differentiate between a consonant and vowel, and adding to the player's balance if they correctly guess a letter. As of now, I have encountered two problems.

First, when checking if a letter is a vowel, it correctly says which is which, and also checks if a vowel CAN be guessed (player needs to have at least a certain amount of money). If they can, it will deduct the necessary amount and move on normally. If not, however, it should disregard the guess and have the player guess again. This works until the player guesses a different letter. What happens is the second guess that the player tries is checked, but the first guess, the vowel which they could not afford, is also checked.

Here is what it looks like:

The word is CANADA

[image]

Basically, the player guessed A at first, but when asked to guess another letter (because they did not have enough money), they guessed C. When updating, the computer updated both for letter A and letter C, which I do not want.

Second, I am trying to have the player's balance update if they correctly guess a letter. For this, I have a separate function setup to update a balance based on the type of guess, but somewhere, the variable becomes undefined. This is the related code that I have for that part:

I am using parameters to do this, what is going wrong?

```js
function spinWheel() {
  spinAmount();
  ask();
}

function spinAmount() {
  var luck = randomNum(0, rewards.length);
  var multiplier = rewards[luck];
  if (multiplier == undefined) {
    spinAmount();
  } else {
    alert("You spun $" + multiplier);
    return multiplier;
  }
  updateBalance(multiplier);
}

function ask() {
  console.log("Prompting");
  var guess = prompt("What letter would you like to guess?");
  var playerGuess = guess.toUpperCase();
  console.log(playerName1 + " guessed " + playerGuess);
  checkGuessType(playerGuess);
}

function checkGuessType(checkMe) {
  console.log("Checking type...");
  if (checkMe.length > 1) {
    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a word.");
  } else if (checkMe == "A" || checkMe == "E" || checkMe == "I" || checkMe == "O" || checkMe == "U" && balance1 < 100) {
    console.log(playerName1 + " tried to guess a vowel.");
    alert("You cannot spin the wheel and guess a vowel!")
    alert("You do not have enough money to buy a vowel. Guess a different letter.");
    ask();
  } else if (checkMe == "A" || checkMe == "E" || checkMe == "I" || checkMe == "O" || checkMe == "U" && balance1 > 100) {
    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a vowel.");
    alert("You cannot spin the wheel and guess a vowel!")
    alert("Since you guessed a vowel, you do not get any money added to your account. Instead, $100 was deducted.");
    isVowel = true;
  } else if (checkMe !== "") {
    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a consonant.");
  } else if (checkMe == "") {
    console.log(playerName1 + " did not guess.");
    alert("Please guess a letter or word.")
    ask();
  }
  checkForGuess(checkMe);
}

function checkForGuess(amIThere) {
  console.log("Checking if letter is present...");
  for (x = 0; x < magicyMagic.length; x++) {
    if (amIThere == magicyMagic.charAt(x)) {
      console.log("Ding ding ding!");
      lettersMatched = lettersMatched + 1;
      isCorrect = true;
      output[x] = amIThere;
      if (isVowel == false) {
        updateBalance();
      } else if (isVowel == true && nowGoing == 1) {
        balance1 = balance1 - 100;
      } else if (isVowel == true && nowGoing == 2) {
        balance2 = balance2 - 100;
      }
      lettersMatched = 0;
      document.getElementById("mysteryWord").innerHTML = output.join("");
      document.getElementById("pl1Messages").innerHTML = "Player 1 - " + playerName1 + " has $" + balance1;
    }
  }
  if (isCorrect == false && amIThere !== "") {
    console.log("Player did not guess correctly...");
    document.getElementById("mysteryWord").innerHTML = output.join("");
    document.getElementById("pl1Messages").innerHTML = "There are no " + amIThere + "'s in the word.";
    lettersMatched = 0;
    document.getElementById("lastMessage").innerHTML = "Player 2 (" + playerName2 + ") will now go.";
  }
  hasBeenGuessed.push(amIThere);
  console.log(hasBeenGuessed[0] + " has been added to the list. Players cannot guess this letter again.");
}

function updateBalance(totalMoneySpun) {
  alert(totalMoneySpun)
  if (nowGoing == 1) {
    balance1 = balance1 + (lettersMatched * totalMoneySpun);
    document.getElementById("pl1Messages").innerHTML = "Player 1 - " + playerName1 + " has $" + balance1;
  }
}
```

Comment: which variable is undefined? It wasn't clear to me

Comment: I made you a snippet. We want a [mcve] with relevant HTML and code

Comment: There are 100 missing things in your code. `rewards, isVowel, nowGoing, magicyMagic, output, balance1` etc I gave up trying to fix your code enough to answer your question